# AWS C# Lambda function code not deployed after successful deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a C# core2.0 Lambda function create on visual studio to Amazon Lambda function.

I am using these commands on command line:

```
dotnet lambda package -c Release -f netcoreapp2.0
```

Which creates the release folder with zip deployment file.

After that I issue:

```
dotnet lambda deploy-function -fn AWSLambda1
```

And that function was created on the AWS
[image]

But When I enter the Lambda function there is not code in it:

[image]

When I try to upload the zip deployment file it is not working and code is not deploying

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issues , uploads the function but not the code... also tried overwriting an existing lambda , no joy.

Comment: Shame, im sure theres just something missing. obviously works in visual studio lambda deployments

Comment: figured it out , see post above

Answer (score 0):

OK , i think I figured this out , when you publish a dotnet lambda project from the CLI by default it creates a DLL - then the deploy function zips and uploads the DLL to AWS lambda.  Naturally you cant then inspect individual code files as they are compiled in the DLL.  Maybe theres some option to upload the raw code files.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda deployment way trough command line.

Step 1 : dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools

Step 2 : dotnet lambda deploy-serverless

**Note**: Step 2 for whole lambda's deployment command it is required to first time deployment.

Step 3 : if you want to deploy specific lambda then use below command.

**dotnet lambda deploy-function Getdata**

**Note** :(*Getdata* is a function name which mention in serverless.template file in resource section)
[image]

Add below configuration in "aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json"
[image]